# FFmpeg: About filter_complex command

Tags: ffmpeg

I use this command.

`ffmpeg  -i Input.mp4 -i logo.png -c:v h264_nvenc -filter_complex  "[0:v]scale=-1:720[video];[1:v][video]scale2ref=(iw/ih)*ih/8/sar:ih/8[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=10:10" output.mp4`

But what does this mean?

**scale2ref=(iw/ih)*ih/8/sar:ih/8**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `scale2ref=(iw/ih)*ih/8/sar:ih/8` does is scale the image height to 1/8th the video's height, and scale the image width to, well, a weird value. If the scale is meant to preserve the image's aspect ratio, use

```
scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih/8
```

(FFmpeg version >= 4.0)

Answer (score 6):

To understand the `-filter_complex` language, it is essential to read this [small chapter of the ffmpeg docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#toc-Filtergraph-description).

You can put the filter description also into a file and use `-filter_complex_script <file>`.

Compare the filter to a function. The parameters are separated by `:`. By-position just `value`, else dictionary-style `name=value`. To start the parameter list, you use `=`, too.

The actual data goes via labels `[<inlabel>]<filter>[<outlabel>]`.
Within a chain of filters (separated by `,`), labels are not necessary.
Chains are separated by `;`.

`ffmpeg -filters | grep scale2ref`

would give you the in and out channels for the `scale2ref` filter (`VV->VV`),
i.e. 2 videos, in and out.

`ffmpeg -help filter=scale2ref` gives you info on the parameters of the filter.
The order of the parameters is not so obvious, as in this case `w` is followed by `width`.
But `w` and `width` are the same. So the actual order is `width,height` of output.

`(iw/ih)*ih/8/sar:ih/8` is thus `width=(iw/ih)*ih/8/sar:height=ih/8`.

To know what variables are predefined/preset for a filter,
you need to look into the
[docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#toc-scale2ref) or even better into the
[source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/vf_scale.c#:%7E:text=var_names).